# Sending a message from an iframe and/or getting notification of a tab focus event

Tags: html, iframe, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener, sendmessage

I need a way to detect if a tab (in Chrome) has focus.

I've tried this:

```
window.addEventListener("focus",function(){
    console.log("Focus event fired")
});
```

But the event only fires after the user clicks somewhere on the page.  I need it to fire whenever a user clicks a tab header, giving that tab focus.  After some research, I found the `visibilitychange` event and it did what I needed but only on HTML5 pages.  So I figured I could just dynamically create an  iframe (with a `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration) containing the event listener and inject it into a webpage:

```
var iframeId = "pmIframeId";
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.id = iframeId;
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

// Set up the iframe structure and declare it HTML5
var idocument = iframe.contentDocument;
idocument.open();
idocument.write("<!DOCTYPE html>");
idocument.write("<html>");
idocument.write("<head></head>");
idocument.write("<body>");

// Write the event listener code to the iframe
var source = chrome.extension.getURL("pmIframe.js");
idocument.write("<script src='"+source+"'></script>");
idocument.write("</body>");
idocument.write("</html>");
idocument.close();
```

The source code for `pmIframe.js` is:

```
function setup(){
    console.log("iframe dom loaded")    // This does indeed write to the console
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(){
        var obj = {};
        obj.action = 'visibilitychange';

        // The following two lines are hardcoded just for testing
        // but refer to a real extension id and an active tab
        var extId = 'jbkncfmkbfgbfcjhchonlpbgajopfbgc';
        var tabId = '17';

        // The following two lines appear to execute (no errors), but my
        // background nor content pages ever get the message
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(tabId, obj, function(){});
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extId, obj, function(){});
    });
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setup);
```

I'm pretty sure the messages are not being sent because my manifest.json does not contain the `externally_connectable` key.  But even if it did, the value specified would have to be at least a second level domain - no "*" allowed - and this has to work on all pages.

My question is: Can I send a message from a iframe I created and injected into a webpage?  Is there a better way of detecting a tab focus event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could listen to [chrome.tabs.onActivated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated) event, it fires when the active tab in a window change.

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
    console.log("Active tab has changed");
});
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you.